X11: Fake XInput clicks on a covered Gtk app
I have a window that listens for XInput events and conditionally forwards them to the window behind it. This works with basic X11 events as I can construct them, but Gtk applications (e.g. caja) ignore those and handle only XInput events.
Is it possible to construct XInput events and send them to a specific window with XSendEvent?
Note that the window in question is below my window, so I can't just emulate a mouse click. Unbinding my window while sending the event is also not an option as it causes noticeable flickering.
Conditional forwarding of events is very important because that behavior is controlled through an external Lua script (forward events that aren't consumed).
I could easily forward all events (and capture them) by making the input shape empty, but that's not what I want to achieve.
For context, the app in question is conky and I'm trying to add scriptable components to it, so it's basically a rectangle with partially interactive content (e.g. buttons that cover only part of the render area).
